# Why does the following JavaScript test show the element as not belonging to the array?

Tags: javascript

The code is very simple and I would be expecting true however it returns false

```
var markets = ["AB", "CD"];
console.log("AB" in markets);
```

Comment: Because this is not how the `in` operator works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: If you are developing for any browser but IE you could use Array.indexOf also a bit more of a complete solution would be to use Jquery's utility method inArray http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're meaning `if (markets.indexOf('AB') !== -1)`. `in` essentially checks if the test is a **property** of the object, not if an element is **contained** within the array.

For more information, look at [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) vs. the [`in operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Comment: +1 for offering the solution. I wasn't willing to go the extra mile. :)

Comment: @cwolves: Indeed, however the article (for `Array.indexOf`) has the source for implementing it when it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Because `in` looks up property names, not values. Your property names are the array indices.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN's page on the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.
>
> `prop` A string or numeric expression representing a property name or array index

Note *a property name or array index*.  The `in` operator does not search for property  values, but for property names.  In this case, the property names are `0` and `1`, so `0 in markets` will return true.

You should use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), in browsers that support it, and shim it in those that don't.

Answer (score 0):

Because `in` is meant for objects, not arrays.  If you want to reliably do this you have to search through each element in the array:

```
for( var i=0, l=markets.length; i<l; i++ ){
    if( markets[i] === 'AB' ){
        // do something
    }
}
```

The following will work, which is what you're thinking:

```
var markets = { AB: 1, CD: 1 };
console.log( "AB" in markets );
```

Comment: Hmmm... I can't agree with your first sentence. An Array is an Object, and it is just as useful for Arrays objects as it is for any other objects. In both cases it will test the existence of a property name instead of a property value.

Comment: @amnotiam -- I was simplifying the concepts :)  For the purposes of understanding this why the OP's code doesn't work, `Array != Object`.  And it's not just as useful for Array objects as writing `aryVar.foo = 'bar'` is just bad form for 99% of people since they don't realize what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

In only works when you are using an object, not an array. So this will work:

```
var markets = {
    AB: 'AB',
    CD: 'CD'
};

'AB' in markets; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

As said `in` won't help you in this case.
I guess you'll have to write a searching function.
Here's one:

```
function inArray(ArrObj, Search){
  var exists = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < ArrObj.length; i++){
    if (ArrObj[i] == Search){
      return true;
      var exists = true;
      break;
    }
    else if ((i == (ArrObj.length - 1)) && (!exists)){
      if (ArrObj[i] != Search){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want something like this, console.log(markets[0]);